# Lunar lander: How to calc acceleration in each step

Tags: physics, physics-engine, simulations, trajectory

I'm trying to make a lunar lander simulator. I'm going to use a simple Euler integration. AFAIK all I've to calculate is the acceleration in each step, and then I should be able to update velocity and position.

I'm following this page:
http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/LM-descent.htm

There's a paragraph I don't really understand:

> Although most operations are self-explanatory, a brief description of
>   acceleration is warranted. Acceleration is broken down into vertical
>   and horizontal components, where the vertical component is normal to
>   the Moon's surface. The instantaneous vertical and horizontal
>   accelerations of a moving body in reference to this surface are
>   Av=Vh^2/r and Ah=–VhVv/r. To this we add the accelerations resulting
>   from gravity and thrust. Gravity, of course, acts vertically downward.
>   The vertical and horizontal components of thrust are a function of the
>   pitch angle.

The author is making a much more realistic simulation here and because of that he is not assuming the Moon is flat. He comes up with two initial values for each acceleration component:

```
    Av=Vh^2/r

    Ah=–VhVv/r
```

1- Seems that Av is the centripetal acceleration, but where does the Ah come from?

2- Are those initial values really needed? In my game the Moon is going to be flat. I thought taking into account thrust/mass and gravity would suffice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The author is working in a [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), as it is probably more suitable for realistic simulations of this kind.

Those are not initial values. They are the **instantaneous** (for each moment in time) components of acceleration, in a polar coordinate system, of an object that is moving tangentially with respect to that coordinate system's origin. `Av` is the 'vertical' component away from the moon's center and `Ah` is the 'horizontal' component along the surface of the moon. Note that the same motion in a cartesian coordinate system would be a non-accelerated one.

For a flat moon you can just add thrust and gravity to get the current acceleration.

Comment: Well, my flat simulation does not match the [expected behavior](http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/LM-descent.pdf). I'm taking into account initial values for altitude, speed and acceleration, yet my lander keeps falling to the ground at increasing speed, and crashes at -230 m/s in the first minute of the descent. Ay is constant (lunar gravity) but doing `vy += ay*dt` seems to increase descent rate faster than it should.

Comment: At lunar gravity (let's say -1.6m/s²) a Vy of -230 m/s should be reached after 143.75s. Is your dt too large, or are you applying the acceleration more than once, perhaps?